# Exibir preview do vídeo que o usuário selecionar pelo input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video

Na minha aplicação o usuário pode selecionar um vídeo para adicionar ao formulário, mas antes de enviá-lo eu gostaria que exibisse o vídeo quando o usuário seleciona o arquivo. Eu consegui fazer isso já com imagens usando o FileReader no JavaScript. Com vídeo não funciona, eu tentei isso mas sem resultado.

Segue como está meu código:

```
function exibirVideoPc() {
      document.getElementById("vid").onchange = function(event) {
        var file = event.target.file;
        var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        document.querySelector("video").src = blobURL;
      }
}
```

O HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="vid" name="vid" accept="video/*" onchange="exibirVideoPc();" required>
   <div class="invalid-feedback">Campo Obrigatório.</div>
</div>
<div id="embed-video" style="text-align:center;">
  <video width="480" controls>
     <source src="" id="video_here">
        Seu navegador não suporta vídeo HTML5.
   </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está usando `onchange` 2 vezes: uma no atributo que chama a função e dentro da função criando um *event handler* `onchange`. Não precisa da função, basta o *event hanlder* que já captura o change do campo.

Agora, precisa pegar o índice `[0]` da API `files` para jogar no `src` do `source`, mas é preciso substituir a tag `video` toda.

Depois se quiser rodar o vídeo após ele ser carregado, use `.play()`:

```js
document.getElementById("vid").onchange = function() {
   var file = this.files[0];
   var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
   
   document.getElementById("embed-video").innerHTML = '<video width="480" controls>'
   +'<source src="'+ blobURL +'" id="video_here">'
   +'Seu navegador não suporta vídeo HTML5.</video>';
   
   document.querySelector("video").play();
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="vid" name="vid" accept="video/*" required>
   <div class="invalid-feedback">Campo Obrigatório.</div>
</div>
<div id="embed-video" style="text-align:center;">
  <video width="480" controls>
     <source src="" id="video_here">
        Seu navegador não suporta vídeo HTML5.
   </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom @Sam ! Era isso mesmo, obrigada!